# jQuery: insert image only if it exists

Tags: jquery, image, url, file-exists

I'm using jQuery to insert an image and blob of text into my document, but I only want to include the image if it actually exists (the image path is a variable, `img_url`, that may or may not reference an existing image).

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
var text = data.html,
    image = '<img class="myimage" src="' + img_url + '" />';

var imageTest = $("<img>");
    imageTest.attr('src', img_url).load(function() {
        alert("image exists");
    }).error(function() {
        alert("image doesn't exist");
        imageTest.remove();
    });

if (imageTest.length) {
    $("#content").html(image + text);   
} else {
    $("#content").html(text);
}
```

While I do get the correct alert based on whether or not the image exists, `imageTest.length` always evaluates to `1`, so I still end up with the image always being inserted into `#content`, even if it's broken.

Where am I going wrong? `imageTest.remove()` should delete the image element if it fails to load, so therefore its length should be `0`, no?

Comment: "existing image"? Needs to be defined. I can think of two interpretations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
var imageTest = $("<img>");
imageTest.attr('src', img_url).load(function() {
     alert("image exists");
     $("#content").html(image + text); // <-- move it here - if loaded successfully add it
}).error(function() {
     alert("image doesn't exist");
     imageTest.remove(); // <-- don't need this since it's not even in the dom
     $("#content").html(text); // <-- move it here - if failed then just add text
});
```

Though I noticed you will probably get [Object object].. You can use append instead or you will have to convert the object into a String

```
var text = "test text";
var imageTest = $("<img>");
imageTest.attr('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/300').load(function () {
  alert("image exists");
  $("#content").empty().append(imageTest).append(text); // <-- move it here - if loaded successfully add it
}).error(function () {
  alert("image doesn't exist");
  imageTest.remove(); // <-- don't need this since it's not even in the dom
  $("#content").html(text); // <-- move it here - if failed then just add text
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/4Ef2z/)

Or as converting it into a string

```
var text = "test text";
var imageTest = $("<img>");
imageTest.attr('src', 'http://dummyimage.com/300').load(function () {
  alert("image exists");
  var img = $('<div/>').append(imageTest.clone()).html(); // get it as a String
  $("#content").html(img + text); // <-- move it here - if loaded successfully add it
}).error(function () {
  alert("image doesn't exist");
  imageTest.remove(); // <-- don't need this since it's not even in the dom
  $("#content").html(text); // <-- move it here - if failed then just add text
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/ZgzPc/)

Answer (score 1):

According to the jquery doumentation, .remove() only removes the matched elements out of the dom, but the object itself will still exist. You could reattach it with

```
$('#example').append(imageTest);
```

You have to reset imageTest

```
imageTest = [];
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason it will always exist is it will return a 404 if the image doesn't reside on the server, which the 404 does, in fact, exist.  JQuery can't detect things on the Server Side.   You should be using PHP or whatever Server Side language you are using to detect whether it exists or not.